# I installed haskell's windows installer obtained from their website after which the command prompt doesn't recognize commands

Tags: haskell, command-prompt

It doesn't even recognize the default commands like cd etc. I uninstalled haskell and it works fine now. What should i do to get it working with haskell?

EDIT: It says:
..........is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: "doesn't recognize commands". Please report what you directly observe (e.g. "the command window displays *this message*, I type *this comnand*, the comnand window displays *this other message*").

Comment: Please tell us where you are getting the windows installer from. And what is your PATH after you run the installer?

Comment: it says "... is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error and it was because I didn't run the program as an administrator. Afterwords it ran fine.

Comment: this directly contradicts what https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/ says, which is `run the following in a PowerShell session (as a non-admin user):`

Comment: actually i did not run it as admin and i ran into the same issue as in the original question. However, the solution was to simply restart my terminal application. I was using Windows Terminal (from Microsoft, does not come with Windows, but have to download it manually) with Powershell 7.2.5, which has tabs. I had to not only close the tab, but also restart it entirely. After I restarted the WIndows terminal application, ghci worked.

Answer (score 1):

> .is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

This is what windows states when the binary location isn't in the system (or user) `PATH` variable. You'd need to add the location of the `ghc` and other binaries to that variable; it can be done either by Windows dialog in `Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables`, or by using a tool such as [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about).

---

That being said the location *should* be added after the default installation, which might suggest the installation failed in one way or another. You could try simply reinstalling and see if it fixes it.

---

To simply see the `PATH` variable set for the command line, type

```
echo %PATH%
```

and see if the Haskell-related folder is there.

Comment: thanks for replying.the installation succeeded. I also ran a hello world program successfully by doing ghci to load the haskell console.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by closing my Windows terminal program then re-opening.

You do not have to run the installer curl/sh script as admin! The https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/ even tells you so:

> To install on Windows, run the following in a PowerShell session (as a non-admin user)

I ran into the same issue on Windows 11 with [Windows Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Terminal) running a tab with Powershell 7.2.5. I tried closing the tab and re-opening the tab, but I still got the error. I had to close the entire Windows terminal program then re-open it, upon which ghci works just fine.