# How to run ghc 8.10.7 installed via GHCup on Windows 10?

Tags: haskell, ghcup

I have just installed GHC 8.10.7 via GHCup on my Windows 10. I have an earlier release already installed (ghc 9.2.1). After installing ghc 8.10.7 I got the following info:

```
In order to run ghc and cabal, you need to adjust your PATH variable.
To do so, you may want to run 'source /c/ghcup/env' in your current terminal
session as well as your shell configuration (e.g. ~/.bashrc).
```

How to understand this information, since when I run `source /c/ghcup/env` in the terminal I get this:

```
PS C:\Users\ephra> source /c/ghcup/env
source: The term 'source' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
PS C:\Users\ephra>
```

And it seems that ghc 8.10.7 is not visible:

```
PS C:\Users\ephra> ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 9.2.1
PS C:\Users\ephra>
```

GHC 8.10.7 folder:

```
C:\ghcup\ghc\8.10.7
```

Answer (score 1):

> To do so, you may want to run 'source /c/ghcup/env' in your current terminal
> session as well as your shell configuration (e.g. ~/.bashrc).

This works in a Linux terminal, but going by your prompt you're using PowerShell on Windows. To use the `ghc` command, you'll need to update your `Path` environment variable. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44272417/17592995) already covers how to modify your `Path` so I'm not going to write that again here - just follow the steps there to add `C:\ghcup\bin` to your path and you should be fine.

NOTE: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho/44272417#comment102409078_44272417) comment below the linked answer to save yourself some time.

Comment: note that the official script from https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/ already modifies your path variable, so the steps in this answer most likely are not actually necessary. What is much more likely is that you need to close your terminal / powershell application, then re-open it in order for the PATH settings that were changed by the installer to update. [See my answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73184330/2990344)